# Git - Push Last Commit Only to Remote

Tags: git

We have a repository with 2 remotes configured (one remote belongs to us, the other the customer).

What is the easiest way to push the last commit (or rather the latest "state" of the files) to the customer's remote while maintaining the full commit history in our remote?

What we are trying to avoid is the customer seeing all our "working" and pre-reviewed code; so they only see the "finished" article.

Comment: Make a new branch that is all of your work squash together

Comment: I thought that might be the case; then push that branch to their remote and pull request it back into master?

Comment: That's what I would do.

Comment: Thanks very much, I'll do it that way